# Cardview Set Background color

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

I am trying to change the Cardview background color dynamically in the Bindview holder of RecylerView like this.

```
holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.LightCyan);
```

The strange thing is the background is applying the almost opposite of the applied color.(#E0FFFF-LightCyan) to 1F0000 -Almost Black)

I had verified few colors here [here](http://www.colortools.net/color_complementary.html) and the result is same.

But if I set like this

```
holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.mContext, R.color.LightCyan));
```

It worked perfectly.(Yes it's the correct way to set).

CardView XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

OS : Android 6.0 HTC

But where is the understanding gap here?

Comment: [Here's your gap](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

method [setCardBackgroundColor](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setCardBackgroundColor(int)) takes color parameter which means that color represented as 4 byte integer in ARGB format, but you pass into method `R.color.LightCyan` which isn't color but index of color inside of application/system resources. To get color you should use [Color.argb(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue)](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) or [Resources.getColor(int index, Theme theme)](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) or use ContextCompat to use it on older platforms.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I was using hard coded colors for tests, but I did not know that the alpha factor was mandatory. I changed `card.setCardBackgroundColor( 0xFF0000 )` to `card.setCardBackgroundColor( 0xFFFF0000 )` and it worked. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Great explanation. Combined with the one below, I did this and it worked great: `cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.gray_light))`

Answer (score 6):

**AS UPDATE ON MARCH 2016**

Android Support Library 23.2.1(latest), a new [getColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor(android.content.Context,%20int)) method has been added to ContextCompat.

So, use:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

from official doc:

> Returns a color associated with a particular resource ID and styled for the current theme.
>
> **getColor(Context context, int id)** Returns a color associated with a
>   particular resource ID Starting in M, the returned color will be
>   styled for the specified Context's theme.

Please check ContextCompat http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html

Comment: Yeah. I am using that. For curiosity i was testing with other method.Thanks.

Comment: work for me this solution, thank u